# FFmpeg settings for YouTube and Facebook video uploads

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-api

Can any FFmpeg experts share their preferred settings for video conversion to both YouTube and Facebook?

For Youtube I am following these guidelines and my video size is 480P @ 24 fps

- Audio Codec: AAC-LC
- Channels: Stereo or Stereo + 5.1
- Sample rate 96khz or 48 khz
- Video Codec: H.264
- Progressive scan (no interlacing)
- High Profile
- 2 consecutive B frames
- Closed GOP. GOP of half the frame rate.
- CABAC
- Variable bitrate. No bitrate limit required
- Color Space: 4.2.0

[Advanced encoding specifications - YouTube Help](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=1728573&guide=1728585&page=guide.cs)

Comment: Since I just noticed it – are you aware that you can vote up questions and answers that you've found useful? So far you haven't cast any votes on Super User, but you definitely have the privileges to and are even encouraged to do so. This is our way of saying "Thanks" for answer that helped you and it'd be a nice gesture to do :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't consider the guidelines as strict requirements. General recommendation is to provide the highest quality that is practical for you to upload. It's that simple; whatever you upload is going to be re-encoded anyway and YouTube will almost always accept whatever you give them. That means you either upload the original content, or if the original is too big you can re-encode it using a high quality. Example using `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset slow -c:a copy output.mkv
```

See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more details–specifically the `-crf` and `-preset` options. Notice that I simply copied the audio, but you may choose to re-encode it if the source contains uncompressed audio.

Your player may not be able to play the output for various reasons, but YouTube certainly will.

Comment: YouTube has happily accepted almost anything I've thrown at it, even 1fps video, out of sync containers, etc.

Comment: This reduced a video recorded in Apple's Quicktime by about 2/3.